“Oh no! Something has gone wrong.” when Screen goes blank
I'm on a new computer with preinstalled Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS using X11 (I migrated my files from my previous computer)
After setting 5 mins delay to turn off screen under Poewr Saving setting, when the 5 mins arrive, I get the “Oh no! Something has gone wrong.” screen.
I noticed this is happening as I'm using ubuntu on xorg instead of Wayland.
